# How do I pass multiple paramaters in javaScript Window command

Tags: javascript

I have a single page application that has back navigation via a back link shown at the top of the page.
Each screen of the application has it's own function, I store the function name and parameters in arrays and have an event listener which uses the JS window function to call the function.

```
    prevPage="showPage1";
    prevParm=['a','b'];     

    prevParm1=("a","b");
    prevParm2='a,b';
    prevParm3=("a","b","c");    

    //window["navHelper"][prevPage](prevParm);
    //window["navHelper"][prevPage]("a","b"); // works 
    //window["navHelper"][prevPage]["a","b"]; 
    
    
    window["navHelper"][prevPage](prevParm3);
```

showPage1 is a function within the navHelper class

This works for a single parameter but not where there are multiple parameters.

How do I pass two parameters to function using window? I tried passing an array and various other methods and can't get it to work.

There is a jsfiddle showing the issue here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zacmarshall/j6Lxa0u1/3/

Comment: you may want to read about function [.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) maybe even [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Maybe you need [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) ..?